# mcts mvc question

Tags: asp.net-mvc

You are developing an ASP.NET MVC 2 Web application. The application contains a controller named
`HomeController`, which has an action named Index. The application also contains a separate area named
Blog. A view within the Blog area must contain an `ActionLink` that will link to the Index action of the
`HomeController`. You need to ensure that the `ActionLink` in the Blog area links to the Index action of the
`HomeController`. Which `ActionLink` should you use?

A. `Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")`
 B. `Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, null)`
 C. `Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {area = "Blog"}, null)`
 D. `Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {area = "Home"}, null)`

Comment: StackOverflow is not here to help people cheat on their certification exams. By copying this question verbatim, you are likely in violation of copyright laws.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is B.

> A. Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")

If you're inside the Blog area, it will look for a Home/Index within the Blog Area.

> B. Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {area = ""}, null)

This will specify that there is no area, and that it should look at the root of the application rather than a specific area.

> C. Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {area = "Blog"}, null)

Again, Home/Index is not in the blog area.

> D. Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new {area = "Home"}, null)

There is no area called "Home".

Comment: i've tried it, it works in my example.

Comment: Your MCTS certificate it's on the mail :)